# Why doesn't bash/echo work in this CMake script?

Tags: linux, bash, cmake, sh

My CMakeLists.txt correctly builds `my_target`.

I tried adding this dummy command as a trial post-build step:

```
 ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (
        TARGET my_target POST_BUILD
        COMMAND "echo I made `ls ${MY_DIR} | wc -l` things")
```

When I run `make my_target` it fails (after building) with

```
/bin/sh: 1: echo I made `ls /foo/bar | wc -l` things: not found
```

If I copy-paste the part from "echo" to "things" into a shell it runs fine

```
I made 3 things
```

The "/bin/sh: 1" prefix suggests that a shell *is* being run with "echo..." as its command, and I tried changing "echo" to "bash echo" so why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/bin/sh: 1: echo I made `ls /foo/bar | wc -l` things: not found
```

The error message means that something is trying to execute a command called, literally, with spaces and ticks, `` echo I made `ls /foo/bar | wc -l` things ``.

So it looks like `cmake` is passing your whole quote string as the executable. Removing the outer quotes should fix that.